# N1QL query to join document, with the latest child (on basis of creationDateTime) in couchbase

Tags: join, couchbase, greatest-n-per-group, sql++

N1QL  query to get the latest document having same other property in a join result of two different documents in couchbase

I have a bucket called "prices", with two different types of documents "intent" and "request"

```
  "intent"  (id = "intent1")
  {
  "locationDSL": "some_location"
  "product": "some_product1"
  }
  "intent"  (id = "intent2")
  {
  "locationDSL": "some_location2"
  "product": "some_product2"
  }
  "request"  (id = "request1")
  {
  "intentId": "intent1",
  "createdDateTime": "2019-04-01",
  "status" : "success"
  }
  "request"  (id = "request2")
  {
  "intentId": "intent1",
  "createdDateTime": "2019-05-01"
   "status" : "failed"
  }
  "request"  (id = "request3")
  {
  "intentId": "intent2",
  "createdDateTime": "2019-06-01",
 "status" : "failed"
  }
  "request"  (id = "request4")
  {
  "intentId": "intent2",
  "createdDateTime": "2019-07-01",
  "status" : "success"
  }
```

so I have 2 requests("request1" and "request2") for "intent1" and 2 requests("request3" and "request4") for intent2,

I need to join "**intent1**" and "**intent2**" with latest requests (request having latest createdDateTime) i.e  "**request2**" and "**request4**" respectively, and also able filter on some fields of latest child document of matching "intentId", so if query for "status" = "success", then it should only return (intentId2 , request4) and not (intent1,request1), since in the latest child "request2" doesn't match with the condition

i am able to join  the documents , but the join is not with latest requests but all requests matching **intent.id**.

This question is similar to 
[[Filter documents using n1ql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973978/filter-documents-using-n1ql][1])
,but I need a join of all the fields in two documents, rather than single field or attributes

Comment: JOIN using ON clause or WHERE clause using the fields you want. After that you want to produce latest document use aggregate query based on MAX as described other post.

Comment: hi vsr, thanks for your reply , but I am getting error when I write like shown in the link,

Comment: SELECT intents, MAX([request.createdDateTime, request])[1] latestRequests
FROM pricescmd request
WHERE request.intentId IS NOT MISSING
GROUP by request.intentId
LETTING intents = (SELECT RAW  intent.* FROM pricescmd intent USE KEYS request.priceChangeIntentId)[0];   //pricescmd is the bucket name

Comment: code 4210:Expression must be a group key or aggregate:

Comment: hi @vsr, i am really stuck for long, I have a deadline to complete, can u please write the full query for the task...I will be very grateful for your help...i am new to couchbase and n1ql

Comment: SELECT intents, MAX([request.createdDateTime, request])[1] latestRequests FROM pricescmd request WHERE request.intentId IS NOT MISSING GROUP by request.intentId LETTING intents = (SELECT RAW intent.* FROM pricescmd intent USE KEYS request.intentId)[0];

Answer (score 3):

Based on your query try the following. The subquery uses covering index and only fetch the latest document in parent query

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON pricescmd(intentId, status, createdDateTime DESC);
SELECT intents, request
FROM (SELECT mx.*
      FROM pricescmd
      WHERE intentId IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY intentId, status
      mx = MAX([createdDateTime, {META().id, intentId, status} ])[1] )  AS d
LET request = (SELECT RAW request FROM pricescmd AS request USE KEYS d.id)[0],
    intents = (SELECT RAW intent FROM pricescmd AS intent USE KEYS d.intentId)[0];
```

Comment: hi @vsr, thks for ur reply, actually I mixed up some field name in my query above while copy pasting from my server, priceChangeIntentId is actually intentId only....

Comment: use updated statement. If you need filter out do that in parent query